# ORA -12953: The request exceed the maximum allowed database size of 11GB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

We have oracle express edition 11g i.e. ORACLE XE 64bit. There is 10GB available space in the database. But system tablespace is 98% full, there are 2 system tabalespaces. 
When we (our startup team) try to ADD or RESIZE the datafile or tablespace using ALTER command we get following error:

ORA -12953: The request exceed the maximum allowed database size of 11GB

What should be done to add or resize the datafile?

[image: error]

Comment: maybe you created some objects on SYSTEM tablespace instead of ordinary tablespaces, did you?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It is an important hint, thanks. The default tablespace for a new user is SYSTEM and it is not always obvious where your tables and objects will go if not specified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What should be done to add or resize the datafile?

Nothing can be done. The XE version is limited to 11GB of data, see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC116)

> **Oracle Database Express Edition**
>    Oracle Database Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an entry-level edition of Oracle Database that
>   is quick to download, simple to install and manage, and is free to
>   develop, deploy, and distribute. Oracle Database XE makes it easy to
>   upgrade to the other editions of Oracle without costly and complex
>   migrations. Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size machine
>   with any number of CPUs, **stores up to 11 GB of user data**, using up to
>   1 GB of memory, and using only one CPU on the host machine. Support is
>   provided by an online forum.

---

You can purchase Standard or Enterprise edition, which don't have this restriction (but you must pay for it).
You can also register in Oracle's [Technology Network](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/index.html) and use any of Oracle's product (including Oracle's Standard and Enterprice database editions from [their download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)) for free, but only for testing and development purposes.
See [this licence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) for details:

> **License Rights and Restrictions**
>  
>    Oracle grants You a nonexclusive,
>   nontransferable, limited license to internally use the Programs,
>   subject to the restrictions stated in this Agreement, only for the
>   purpose of developing, testing, prototyping, and demonstrating Your
>   application and only as long as Your application has not been used for
>   any data processing, business, commercial, or production purposes, and
>   not for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As krokodilko says, it's a license limit.

Try to find some garbage or old data to delete... maybe some log table or something like that!

```
select owner||'.'||segment_name,segment_type, trunc(sum(bytes/1024/1024/1024),5) GB
 from dba_segments
group by owner,segment_name,segment_type
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30129768)