# Cannot start Oracle-XE 18c due to being full

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle18c

I am unable to start a container inside oracel 18c xe , when using command "Alter Datbase Open" it gives error

**"ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB"**

Upon searching internet i have found a way which says

**"The only way was to append the XE datafiles in a "auxiliary" Oracle 18c home"**

But i am unable to understnad how to mount only single tablespace from my xe database into Home version and remove not required stuff from the tablespace to free up space. Any help regarding this is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286018/ora-12953-the-request-exceed-the-maximum-allowed-database-size-of-11gb

Comment: you should move to standard edition , at least.  Or remove any data you don't need from your current XE installation. XE is for testing purposes, and 11gb is the limit

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez Thank you for the response , I cannot remove any data since the database is unable to start that is the problem. The way i find out is somehow "append the XE datafiles in a "auxiliary" Oracle 18c home" the problem is if i take tablespace file from XE and append it in a standard database it doe snot show any of my schema or any other thing so how can i remove data from the tablespace when i cannot even see anything

Comment: did you have for any change a bigfile tablespace in your XE database ? are you getting the error when you try to mount the database or when you try to open it ?

Comment: Have a look at [this piece by Flavio Casetta](https://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-way-out-of-ora-12952-request.html). He wrote it for an older version of XE when the limit was only 4GB but it provides some techniques for investigating your situation and (with luck) resolving it.

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez There are big tablespaces , and i am getting error when opening database CSD is accessible however container XEPDB1 is not which is needed

Comment: what I meant is if you have tablespaces of type BIGFILE

Comment: Actually i cannot check that since i am unable to open database container , can tablespace files of a container be checked from root cotnainer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Oracle XE which allows a BigFile tablespace being created in a container DB and grow beyond the DB size limit imposed by Oracle Express Edition. The bug is fixed on version 19.1.0.

Unfortunately there is no workaround for this bug.

You might try to open the database with the problematic tablespace in OFFLINE and perform the following actions:

1.Start the database in mount state

```
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT
```

2.Put the tablespace in offline,

```
SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE xxxxx OFFLINE IMMEDIATE;
```

3.Open the database

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN ;
```

In this status, the problematic tablespace is offline, so you can't access any element on it. Remove everything you don't need from other tablespaces ( USERS , etc) and resize others to a lower size ( UNDO , TEMP, SYSTEM ), if possible. Then, try also to resize the problematic datafile ( if the data is beyond the HWM it won't work ).

Finally, put the tablespace that was offline online again and see if the total size of the database is lower than the limit. Then try to open the database.

Comment: Thank you for the details answer , however the tablespace occupying the largest space is USERS tablespace other then this all the tablespaces are only system such as sysaux , undotbs etc , i tried offlining users tablespace but i am still getting same error

Comment: Also i would like to mention a person on link https://community.oracle.com/thread/4318928 mentioned that "the only way was to  append the XE datafiles in a "auxiliary" Oracle 18c home" can you please help me on how this could be achieved i.e. i have a home edition database on other system but how can i append datafiles from XE and then check and remove contents from file

Comment: did you try to reduce system to the minimum, undotbs to the minimum and temp to the minimum. It is your only option

Comment: Thats the problem how can i do it since i cannot open database container which contains  these talespaces , can i apply changes to XEPDB1 container tablespaces from CDBROOT?

Comment: did you try to open the container and run ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = xxx, then resize ?? Do you have a backup of your database ?? or an export datapump ??

Comment: I tried running ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER , then resize table space , i got error "ORA-01109: database not open" , I have complete system level backup of last two days but restoring both didnt help got same error this means that this issue was happening for quite sometime but when system restarted database container was unable to start , do you have idea regarding "append the XE datafiles in a "auxiliary" Oracle 18c home" method

Comment: THe tablespaces using most spaces are SYSAUX=3GB , UNDOTBS=2.5GB , USERS=9GB

Comment: XE is a really shitty version. You could create another database in 18c standard edition or enterprise edition, and then restore the XE backup in a database empty

Comment: I am sorry but i do not have much experience with standard edition , I am assuming you want me to take an rman backup from XE and restore it to standard edition?

Comment: I believe it is your only chance. If you can't resize UNDOTBS or SYSTEM in the container database, you need to restore the rman backup in a standard edition database

Comment: So what i now need to do is create a database in an standard edition database then restore rman backup from XE to that database correct?

Comment: yes. the auxiliary database option is a bit more complicated because you need to create a database as primary , then configure the xe as auxiliary, which is far more complicated than just restore

Comment: Ok thank you i am going to try the rman method although i am not sure if rman restores properly from XE to standard addition ,  i am going to create a database with SID XE and a container as XEPDB1 and then try to restore rman backup to that, will post what i get , let me know if there is any problem with this method , thank you

Comment: HernandezThere is an issue with the rman , the xe database that i have is in linux environment however the standard edition i have installed is in windows envionrment and it is not able to get proper locations fo rbackup from control file when recovering what changes i will have to make to control file and how can yo uplease give me a little guidance